# JComboBox ActionListener doesn't work

Tags: java, swing, combobox

I'd like to get back every second elements of an array (so in this case 2. and 4.).

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;


public class tester2 extends JFrame{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    String [] corps = {"IBM", "Apple", "Oracle", "Google"};
    JComboBox <String> cb = new JComboBox <> ();

    JLabel l1 = new JLabel();

    public tester2() {
        f.setSize(500, 300);
        f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setTitle("Tester 2");
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        f.add(cb, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        f.add(l1);

        // Combo
        cb.removeAllItems();
        cb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                for (int i = 1; i < corps.length; i=+2) {
                     String tempRes = corps[i];
                     System.out.println(tempRes);
                     cb.addItem(tempRes);
                }

            }
        });


    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        new tester2();  
    } 
}
```

More details, more details, more details, more details, more details, more details, more details, more details, more details, more details, more details, more details, more details, more details, more details, more details.

Thanks

Comment: start your loop at 0 not at 1

Comment: *"I'd like to get back every second elements of an array (so in this case 2. and 4.)."* I'd like a flying pony that excretes ice-cream. Now we've both discussed what we'd like. Do you have a **question** we can **answer**?

Comment: Why this code doesn't get any results back? For example System.out.println(tempRes); -> doesn't print anything

Comment: Well there are a number of factors behind that. 1) The action listener will only fire when the user has selected an item from the combo. 2) No items are ever added to the combo to select. 3) But even if they had been added, `cb.removeAllItems();` would have removed them! - Under what circumstances do you think the `actionPerformed` method will be called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't seeing anything because `ActionEvent` for a `JComboBox` is only fired when an item is selected.

Since your combobox is empty, this doesn't happen.

You could put a default value so that your `ActionListener` gets called.

Also it is probably better to put `removeAllItems()` in the `actionPerformed` method, so that you clear the combobox just before populating it .

One last note : the change from `i = +2` to `i += 2`, because `i = +2` means `i=2`, and you go into an infinite loop with index 2 .

```
    // Combo
    cb.addItem("--filler--");

    cb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {

            cb.removeAllItems();

            for (int i = 1; i < corps.length; i += 2) {
                String tempRes = corps[i];
                System.out.println(tempRes);
                cb.addItem(tempRes);
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Interesting. Have you tried it? This doesn't fill the combobox for me.

Comment: @fucorogu : Sure, but you have to select the "filler" item to trigger the action. Also see last edit.

Comment: Anyway why should I use addActionListener? If I remove these:     cb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {    -> then I don't need to select the --filler-- to get the result.

Comment: @fucorogu : Yes indeed, you can populate the combobox from the beginning without ActionListener, but keep this piece of code in case you want to populate/refresh it from a click on a button, for instance.